# Prove Uncountable set minus a countable set is uncountable

Tags: general-topology

Let B be a countable set, and let A be an uncountable set. Prove that A-B is uncountable

Comment: Why don't you share what you've gotten so far, so we know that you've displayed some personal effort before asking?

Comment: Hint: use that if at least one of $X,Y$ are infinite sets, then $|X \cup Y| = \max\{|X|,|Y|\}.$

Answer (score 2):

Let if possible $A-B$ countable,then $A=B\cup (A-B)$ will be countable since $B$ is given countable and union of two countable sets is countable.

Hence $A-B$ uncountable.